# Higher SIC and lower S.E. of residuals

Tags: time-series, model-selection, aic, bic

I used the Schwarz Information Criterion (a.k.a., BIC) and the Akaike Information Criterion (AIC) to select the models for a time series Analysis. AIC got me an ARMA (5,4) and SIC got me ARMA (2,1). So I did the regressions for these two models.

What I don't get is, the S.E. of residuals is smaller for the AIC-Model (ARMA (5,4)) than for the SIC- Model (ARMA(2,1)). Nevertheless it has a higher Schwarz Criterion on the Printout than the other model (Akaike Criterion is lower though).

In the example I have, all three values are lower all together for two different printouts. Should I disregard the SIC and focus on S.E. of residuals while choosing one model?